# Property error of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, meteor

```
router.post('/:token',(req,res)=>{
let language= req.query.l
let name= req.query.n
let param =[]

if(req.path.length == 5){
param.push({
language=language
},{
name=name
})


ddp.person_connected(param,function(err,res){
    if(err){
res.err=err
        }else{

        res.sucess=true
        res.send(param).listen
    }
})
res.sendStatus(200) 

}else{
    res.sendStatus(401)
}
})
```

I want to check if my path ( token ) is equal to the path length that's working, i can get all the data but i want to store it on my database, so i get the error

> TypeError: Cannot set property 'err' of undefined

Maybe i have to do a promise ?

Comment: Can you please indent your code properly?

Comment: @Taieb People here take their time to help you, so take the time to format your code properly.

Comment: @d3L Sorry i edited it, i think it's ok right now.

Answer (score 0):

try this, You have given res variable for boxes_connected callback and route also.

```
router.post('/:token', (req, res) => {
    let language = req.query.l
    let name = req.query.n

    if (req.path.length == 5) {
        let param = [{
            language
        }, {
            name
        }];
        ddp.person_connected(param, function (err, resp) {
            if (err) {
                res.err = err
            } else {
                res.sucess = true
                res.send(param).listen
            }
            res.sendStatus(200)
        })
    } else {
        res.sendStatus(401)
    }
})
```

Comment: `TypeError: Cannot set property 'err' of undefined` this right?

Comment: I get no error message but i can't retrieve the data.

Comment: i think i need to do a promise so i can check the token that i have in my database and the one in my request.

Comment: no need of the promise, you can do that with callback also.

Comment: could you explain it to me how to dit, right now i get an error on the first if, even if my token is right.

Comment: can you share URL with the token, which you are trying?

Comment: http://localhost:2002/00SbiRpRSzP339Ev79? 

So i need to get the token 00SbiRpRSzP339Ev79 without the / 

when i do console.log(req.path) 

i get the token + "/" 

i want to get it without the "/" so i can compare it with the token in the database.

Comment: ìnstead of `req.path` use `use req.params.token`, It'll give only token. `/00SbiRpRSzP339Ev79` in this case path length will be more than 5. In the code you are restricting that `req.path.length == 5`.

Comment: The problem in my database the token is without the / , right now my problem is that the function is not comparing the token in my DB and the one i put in th param, even if i enter a 5 char token i get a sucess message

Answer (score 0):

You have defined variable "res" twice. 
Try changing the line to

ddp.person_connected(param,function(err,response){